# Where can I find all classes and methods from the APS Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

Where can I consult the entire APS Viewer API? The official Autodesk Platform Services page seems to be incomplete and it is very tedious to search. There is no search engine for classes and methods.
I can't find information on what methods have other extensions like 'Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension' or others.

It would be great to be able to consult the documentation as in the page of https://apidocs.co/#

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it may be lacking in some areas, https://aps.autodesk.com/developer/documentation is the best place to find documentation for the Viewer API. I've been personally collecting feedback from customers (as well as my own), and I'm communicating with the engineering team to have those addressed. If you have any specific issues, please send those to `aps (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`.